# C++ mapnik undefined reference to rule

Tags: c++, linux, qt, mapnik

Sorry for my bad english. I just installed mapnik, but I just can't run demo file using c++ and Qt Creator. First of all, I fixed all linking issues with no sweat, but now it gives me an "Undefined reference to" error. I'm pasting here the output:

> Blockquote
>   /home/mattia/GLWorks/mapnikTest/main.cpp:72: error: undefined reference to `mapnik::rule::set_filter(std::shared_ptr >, mapbox::util::recursive_wrappermapnik::binary_node, mapbox::util::recursive_wrappermapnik::binary_node, mapbox::util::recursive_wrappermapnik::binary_node, mapbox::util::recursive_wrappermapnik::binary_node, mapbox::util::recursive_wrappermapnik::binary_node, mapbox::util::recursive_wrappermapnik::binary_node, mapbox::util::recursive_wrappermapnik::binary_node, mapbox::util::recursive_wrappermapnik::binary_node, mapbox::util::recursive_wrappermapnik::binary_node, mapbox::util::recursive_wrappermapnik::binary_node, mapbox::util::recursive_wrappermapnik::binary_node, mapbox::util::recursive_wrappermapnik::unary_node, mapbox::util::recursive_wrappermapnik::binary_node, mapbox::util::recursive_wrappermapnik::binary_node, mapbox::util::recursive_wrappermapnik::regex_match_node, mapbox::util::recursive_wrappermapnik::regex_replace_node, mapbox::util::recursive_wrappermapnik::unary_function_call, mapbox::util::recursive_wrappermapnik::binary_function_call > > const&)'

What is missing on this program? Thank you!

PS. My OS is OpenSuse 42.1 Leap

Comment: It seems you are not linking against mapnik itself.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Because I fixed another linking issue like this yesterday, giving "LIBS += /usr/lib64/libmapnik.so.3.0.9"
and this new error is strange, it seems like it requires mapbox. But why should I link mapbox on a demo file? I don't really get this choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed uninstalling and reinstalling mapnik from website source, not from Yast